# Put a text onto a game-object BUT as if it was painted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, rendering, gameobject

I was looking for this answer on the web for some time. 
But apparently my search phrases were wrong or it is really that hard. But I doubt it.

Imagine, I have any 3d-body. A sphere, cylinder or cube.

I want to put a text onto that object. As if it was a sticker or painted onto that object. 
Meaning, it would follow the objects curves or edges, if wrapping around them. I managed to create some texts which are ALWAYS in front or behind my object. But that is not what I want.

The closest to what I want looks like this:

[image]

I cannot believe, that I need to code for this. It must be achievable via child/parents, canvas and text, JUST using the inspector and components.

Is this so ?

Comment: I think you do need some code that would place each vertex of the text in the correct position, but I am not sure how that would work.
Usually what I am doing is just creating a texture with the text but I am sure it is not what you are looking for

Comment: Well, Unity can apply a texture to a UV mapped model for you but generally you'll create those outside of Unity.  You could hypothetically implement that into the unity editor yourself but that's far too broad a topic for one question. There might be a unity asset that already exists for that, but asking for a library is off topic for stack overflow. I would recommend looking for tutorials on "uv mapping". Good luck!

Comment: I'd look into Decal systems, and then extend them by making your own text-to-texture feature. (since those decal systems use textures).

Comment: If you want to use it on not so irregular surface, and have some fix texts then you can also use the Unity Projector: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html.

Comment: Are there specific reasons for the votes which are requesting closing this question? 
If so, I apologize, if this one lacks "code to be corrected".

Comment: I'm retracting my close vote because @derHugo found a really slick solution for an object that's already UV mapped.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

tl;dr: If your mesh is properly UV mapped, you can render the text onto a `RenderTexture` and use it as the texture for your object's material

---

Not that simple but here is how you can achieve something similar. **This requires your 3D models to be correctly UV mapped so you can simply apply a flat texture to it.** The setup may sound complex but it is really cool ;)

1. Create a [`RenderTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html): In the `Asset` do <kbd>right mouse click</kbd> → `Create` → `RenderTexture` and call it however you like e.g. `TextTexture`

[image]

- To have a better resolution later increase it's `size` to e.g. `2048*2048` depedning on your needs of course.

[image]

2. Create a new Material

[image]

- using the just created `RenderTexture` as `Albedo`
- and set the `RenderingMode` to `Fade` (in order to later have it's background transparent)

[image]

3. Create a new [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and call it e.g. `TEXT`

[image]
[image]

4. In you normal main `Camera` under `Culling Mask` **exclude** the just created `TEXT` layer. So it will not render our Text content

[image]

5. Add a new `Camera` to your scene (it will only render the text) and call it e.g. `TextCamera`

[image]

and make the following settings:

[image]

- Remove its `AudioListener` component
- `Clear Flags` → `Solid Color`
- `Background` → Color actually doesn't matter but make sure to set the Alpha level to `0`!
- `Culling Mask` → Nothing except the created `TEXT` layer
- `Target Texture` → The created `RenderTexture`

Now you already have a Material with a dynamically changeable Texture with transparent background and whatever content you like. So lets make it e.g. a UI.Text

6. To your scene (I did it simply as child of the `TextCamera` so I can simply move it out of sight in the SceneView while working on other stuff) add a `Text` (including the Canvas etc - Unity usually adds it automatically)

[image]

- Make all GameObjects (Canvas and Text) have the Layer `TEXT` so they will not be rendered by the normal `Camera` but only by the `TextCamera`.

[image]
[image]

- Make sure the `Canvas` uses `RenderMode = WorldSpace` (it won't work with overlay canvas)!
- Place the `Canvas` about e.g. `3` units in front of the `TextCamera` (or wherever you like so the Text is visible in the texture later)

[image]

- To have better Text resolution I would also on the `Text`
- on the `RectTransform` set `width = 1000`, `height = 1000`, `Scale = 0.001, 0.001, 0.001`
- In the `Text` component set `Font Size = 300`
- Just to be sure disable the `Raycast Target` option

[image]

And now you can simply apply the created material to your 3D Object and hit play and should see that it gets completely transparent except having the text on it.

[image]

So in order to use it as overlay for a 3D object you could e.g. simply duplicate the original object, call one e.g. `Inner` the other one `Outer` and make `Inner` a child of `Outer`. Now on the `Outer` you set our Text material. This works since a material using `Fade` as render mode is rendered on a different render chain which is rendered on top of the default one.

→ Tadaaa 3D object with Text applied to its surface and can even dynamically change the text and its properties like color etc

[image]

---

#### The whole thing dynamic (Except creating Layers)

Since you asked: Yes you *can* make this all in a script ... **except creating new Layers! This is not possible on runtime!**

So you have to know all the Layers you will use beforehand then you can do something like

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class TextOnObjectManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference via Inspector if possible
    [SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;
    [SerializeField] private string LayerToUse;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // 0. make the clone of this and make it a child
        var innerObject = new GameObject(name + "_original", typeof(MeshRenderer)).AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        innerObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
        // copy over the mesh
        innerObject.mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        name = name + "_textDecal";

        // 1. Create and configure the RenderTexture
        var renderTexture = new RenderTexture(2048, 2048, 24) { name = name + "_RenderTexture" };

        // 2. Create material
        var textMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));

        // assign the new renderTexture as Albedo
        textMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", renderTexture);

        // set RenderMode to Fade
        textMaterial.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
        textMaterial.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        textMaterial.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
        textMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
        textMaterial.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
        textMaterial.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
        textMaterial.renderQueue = 3000;

        // 3. WE CAN'T CREATE A NEW LAYER AT RUNTIME SO CONFIGURE THEM BEFOREHAND AND USE LayerToUse

        // 4. exclude the Layer in the normal camera
        if (!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;
        mainCamera.cullingMask &= ~(1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer(LayerToUse));

        // 5. Add new Camera as child of this object
        var camera = new GameObject("TextCamera").AddComponent<Camera>();
        camera.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
        camera.backgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
        camera.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.Color;
        camera.cullingMask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer(LayerToUse);

        // make it render to the renderTexture
        camera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
        camera.forceIntoRenderTexture = true;

        // 6. add the UI to your scene as child of the camera
        var Canvas = new GameObject("Canvas", typeof(RectTransform)).AddComponent<Canvas>();
        Canvas.transform.SetParent(camera.transform, false);
        Canvas.gameObject.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
        Canvas.renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;
        var canvasRectTransform = Canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvasRectTransform.anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(0, 0, 3);
        canvasRectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.one;

        var text = new GameObject("Text", typeof(RectTransform)).AddComponent<Text>();
        text.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform, false);
        var textRectTransform = text.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        textRectTransform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.001f;
        textRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(2000, 1000);

        text.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
        text.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        text.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        text.color = Color.red;
        text.fontSize = 300;
        text.horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Wrap;
        text.verticalOverflow = VerticalWrapMode.Overflow;

        Canvas.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer(LayerToUse);
        text.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer(LayerToUse);

        text.text = "This is a dynamically generated example!";

        // 7. finally assign the material to the child object and hope everything works ;)
        innerObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = textMaterial;
    }
}
```

Basically reproducing all the steps from before. Since we can't create or edit Layers on runtime you have to know them beforehand and enter it as `LayerToUse`.

I created every thing as child of the original object so it is easy to control and change it also later on runtime.

[image]

---

**Update**

In newer Unity versions I'd recommend to exchange the `Text` by [`TextMeshProUGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/TMPObjectUIText.html) which supports a lot more text formatting and autoscaling etc.

Comment: THX a lot.

This is quite complex and a lot of work inside the "designer-IDE".

Would a code-approach get rid of some steps  ?

Comment: Well you need an individual Layer foreach new Text so adding this on runtime would become quite tricky since you can't edit/add Layers dynamically on runtime. It depends a bit on your needs but in general: Yes you can basically do all the steps in a script as well ... except as said creating new Layers

Comment: I am quite disappointed, that this feature is so "unhandy". I believe, I am not the only person having such a requirement. And it is just for fun, so no real productive issue.

Comment: Please see my update .. I just added a script version that makes the entire setup for you on an object. However the Layers you will still have to set beforehand

Comment: Ooh, clever solution using a render texture. Very nice.

Comment: Thanks a ton , for this purpose i spent hours and hours ..... Thaks you

Comment: Wow thats brilliant! Is it possible to share the unity project?

Comment: @temre I fear it doesn't exist anymore ;) actually I built this from scratch just for the answer .. but the script at the bottom should actually set it all up on runtime (except the one layer you'd have to create beforehand)

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes that help.

1. Your code: *name = name + "_textDecal";* is probably meant to be *innerObject.name = name + "_textDecal";*
2. in this same area, you need to add *innerObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;* and *innerObject.transform.localRotaton = Quaternion.identity;* otherwise the text doesn't seem to follow the object if it is moved or rotated

But the real problem I find is this (on Unity 2020.1.f1):  the texture of the original mesh is only properly shown within the Unity editor -- standalone builds show a black object (or whatever the camera background color is).

Is the issue one I see explained somewhat vaguely in RenderTexture docs (that I cannot immediately locate again) that hinted that I needed to include a Texture (Material?) in my Resources folder that has similar shaders to the ones used in my RenderTexture?

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with a UI Text game object and the 3D Object.

The steps are as follows:

- In your empty scene, create a 3D Cube.

[image: Cube]

- Create a UI Text object.
- Drag the Canvas to become a child of the cube.
- Set the Canvas to World Space render mode, remove the Canvas Scaler component and set Width = Height = 1 and all Pos = 0.

[image: Canvas]

- Set the text Width = Height = 100, all Scale = 0.01 and Pos Z = -0.5.

[image: Text]